# XCTest crashes when travis tries to run tests

Tags: ios, travis-ci, xctool

I am trying to setup travis to run my existing tests. I am using XCTest and can successfully run the test locally with `xctool test`. I have the `.xctool-args` file setup with all of the needed configuration. On Travis the build completes but xctest is crashing. Here is the crash log

```
Test did not run: the test bundle stopped running or crashed before the test suite started.
CRASH REPORT: xctest_2014-05-07-064505_Traviss-Mac-32.crash
Process:         xctest [1517]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/Developer/usr/bin/xctest
Identifier:      xctest
Version:         13.2
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  sim [1514]
Responsible:     xctest [1517]
User ID:         501
Date/Time:       2014-05-07 06:44:57.294 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  AFA30136-CB6D-6480-DAA2-9E74869E8355
Crashed Thread:  8  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000704f535a
VM Regions Near 0x704f535a:
    __LINKEDIT             000000002010d000-0000000020113000 [   24K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000008fef2000-000000008ff25000 [  204K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: reachabilityRef
iPhone Simulator (external launch) , iPhone OS 7.1 (unknown/11D167)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more a workaround than an answer. Tests with xctool work locally but there appears to be a problem with xctool on travis. I solved my problem by using xcodebuild instead of default test script that uses xctool.

```
language: objective-c
script:
- xcodebuild -scheme SchemeName -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone Retina
  (4-inch),OS=7.1'  test
```

Comment: Hoorah! Finally got Travis working this way. I see no reason to use xctool nowadays.